# Is it possible to implement JMS, Spring and Tibco EMS on a standalone Java app?

Tags: java, spring, jms, tibco, spring-jms

So here's my problem!

I Have a Tibco EMS topic with authentication

I have a standalone app I'd like to pub and consume messages from this

And I'd like to do this through Springs JMSTemplate, Listener etc.

E.x listener:

```
public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {
            //TODO DAO interface to write to db
            System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Message must be of type TestMessage");
    }
}
```

}

Sample publisher:

```
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
```

public class ExampleProducer {

private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

```
public ExampleProducer(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
}

public void sendMessage() {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("Example Message");
}
```

}

```
and here's some of the properties:
```

jms.jndi.initialContextFactory=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
jms.jndi.urlPkgs=com.tibco.tibjms.naming

jms.jndi.providerUrl=tibjmsnaming:/**********.net:***

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is a fairly typical setup.

You will just require some extra configuration to compensate for the fact that you are not operating inside a Java EE environment. Thus you don't have simple JNDI lookups via resource refs.

Comment: Could you please provide more information or point me in the direction or some good examples online. I also thought it would be fairly typical but there seems to be nothing out there that uses tibco! Also the JNDI problem is exaclty the main issue I was expecting. 

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Never used tibco myself, but what you are looking for is typically referred to as a 'thin client'.  The configuration and jar requirements will be specific for the vendor.